# Need some clarification regarding reference types

Tags: c#, oop, reference

So I'm reading an article by Jon Skeet regarding parametering passing in C# and he's made the following example to explain how reference types work, but I can't wrap my head around it.

```
StringBuilder first = new StringBuilder();
first.Append("hello"); 
StringBuilder second = first;
first.Append(" world");
first = new StringBuilder("goodbye");
Console.WriteLine(first); // Prints goodbye
Console.WriteLine(second); // Still prints hello world
```

When we're assigning the value of the `second` variable are we just setting that value to the reference of the `StringBuilder` object?

Also as a bonus question, if we would change the reference of the `second` variable to something else(setting it to a null value for example), would the reference to the first `StringBuilder` object then be irretrievable? Or is there any way to retrieve all created objects of a certain type?

Comment: Your bonus question is not that clear. Do you mean if you'd do: `StringBuilder second = first; second = null;` for example?

Comment: Right that's exactly what I mean, I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When we're assigning the value of the second variable are we just
>   setting that value to the reference of the StringBuilder object?

Yes. We just *copy a pointer* to the memory that contains "hello world".

> if we would change the reference of the second variable to something
>   else, would the reference to the first StringBuilder object then be
>   irretrievable? Or is there any way to retrieve all created objects of
>   a certain type?

Yes, and the memory allocated by it, will become a candidate for garbage collection as there is no any pointer referencing to it.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the GC will dispose of the object as soon as there are no longer any pointers to it? Is this more or less instantenous?

Comment: @OverlyExcessive - no, it is *not* instantaneous. It will happen "some time in the future", maybe when memory pressure becomes high (the system needs extra memory) or has a spare moment to clean up.

Comment: @OverlyExcessive: It *may* even not happen at all, if it ends up into generation 2, so you will get a memory leak. [Fundamental of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee787088%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#generation)

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder second = first;
```

means that the `second` variable now holds the reference to the same place in the memory as `first` variable.

However, this line:

```
first = new StringBuilder("goodbye");
```

Now says that `first` gets a brand new reference to a new object, thus breaking the connection between `first` and `second`.

Answer (score 0):

Line

```
first = new StringBuilder("goodbye");
```

breaks the connection between those two objects.

So first has `goodbye` and second has `hello world`